# Select Max() and Min() date and Sum up quantity

Tags: sql

I have table with data as below

```
StartDate   EndDate      ID        Qty
2017-09-01 2017-10-01 PJFC1000205   1
2017-10-01 2017-11-01 PJFC1000205   2
2017-11-01 2017-12-01 PJFC1000205   3
2017-12-01 2018-01-01 PJFC1000205   4
```

I wish sum up the qty and wish the output as below

```
StartDate      EndDate      ID           Qty
2017-09-01    2018-01-01   PJFC1000205    10
```

Is it possible to do so?  How I can do it?
I'm using MSSQL 2014.
Please guide me, thanks.

Comment: Can you please specify which DB you are using?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the group by on ID and aggregate functions on the other fields should do the trick.

```
 SELECT min(Start_Date), max(End_Date), ID, sum(Qty)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: so curious, why previously I try group by but it not work.  Now it work.  Thanks

Comment: Post your query and maybe I can review it.